# what could be the cause of caps light on and never goes off

Tags: windows-10, capslock

My system caps light switched on by it self 4 days ago and since then I have been trying to switch it off but couldn't and don't really know the cause of it

Comment: Is your keyboard stuck in capitals lock mode, or is it just the light that is permanently on? Have you unplugged it? Have you rebooted the OS? How is the BIOS setting? You need to tell us a lot more about what you have done before we have a hope of offering a solution.

Comment: The button is not pressed down, I have rebooted, off, on removed the battery several times and it still remains the same the light is just permanently on I have hit the button several times also and nothing changed

Comment: You still haven't answered my first question: is the keyboard always typing in upper case?

Comment: All the buttons in the keyboard are working

Comment: That _still_ doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Ok what answer do you want?

Comment: Does the keyboard always produce upper case? Or is it only that the indicator is on, regardless of the actual capitals lock state? I can't put it more plainly.

Comment: Does the keyboard always produce upper case? Yes it does.

Comment: Two obvious things to try are another keyboard on that system and that keyboard on another system.